# Replace any numeric sequence with one character

Tags: java, regex, replace

If I have a string with numbers and characters and I want to replace the numbers with a certain character, I can use replace with a regualr expression.  However it replaces EVERY number with that character. What would be the best way to change this behavior?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Regexp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner firstname = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter you name");
        String firstname1 = firstname.next();
        firstname1 = firstname1.replaceFirst("[^A-Za-z]", ":");
        System.out.println(firstname1);
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

See the above code.  If I were to enter in jsahdk1283, it would return jsahdk::::, when I just want jsahdk:.  Is this possible?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: maybe "[^A-Za-z]+"

Comment: Use `replaceAll("\\d+",":")`

Comment: I like both of these solutions

Answer (score 1):

As [RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796235/replace-any-numeric-sequence-with-one-character#comment66885224_39796235) and [TheLostMind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796235/replace-any-numeric-sequence-with-one-character#comment66885286_39796235) mentioned in the comments, you should use a quantifier like this:

```
firstname1 = firstname1.replaceFirst("[^A-Za-z]+", ":");
```

Here, the `+` coming after the character class means "one or more".

Note that `[^A-Za-z]` will match ANYTHING that is not an English letter, such as accented characters and punctuation. It's therefore a better idea to use `\d`.

```
firstname1 = firstname1.replaceFirst("\\d+", ":");
```

Comment: If you want to replace _only_ the digits, use "\\d+", because "[^A-Za-z]+" replaces all other characters that are not letters as well. And this would include foreign language letters like é or ä, colons, commas etc.